# How to create a dynamic component from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-easyui

I am trying to create a ComboBox in with html and Javascript. So I got to start the idea with this link. [MultiSelect Combo](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboBox) (MultiSelect ComboBox)

In this link I take all the resources and placed in my local and got the desired result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Format in ComboBox - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/easyui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Custom Format in ComboBox</h2>
    <p>This sample shows how to custom the format of list item.</p>
    <div style="margin:20px 0"></div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:26%;" data-options="
                    url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',
                    method: 'get',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    textField: 'text',
                    panelWidth: 350,
                    multiple:true,
                    formatter: formatItem,
                    label: 'Language:',
                    labelPosition: 'top'
                    ">
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formatItem(row){
            var s = '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + row.text + '</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="color:#888">' + row.desc + '</span>';
            return s;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want my Inputbox to be Dynamic, So I can use it anywhere and any number of times by passing div and others required attributes.

What I tried here is
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Format in ComboBox - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/easyui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/NewCombo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Custom Format in ComboBox</h2>
    <p>This sample shows how to custom the format of list item.</p>
    <div style="margin:20px 0"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myCombo = new NewCombo({
            url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',
            method: 'get',
            valueField: 'id',
            textField: 'text',
            panelWidth: 350,
            multiple:true,
            //formatter: formatItem,
            label: 'Language:',
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And JS Code is
Js Code

```
NewCombo = function(args){
    var mydiv =   "<div style="margin-bottom:20px">"+"
            <input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:26%;" data-options="
                    url: 'JSON/combobox_data1.json',\
                    method: 'get',\
                    valueField: 'id',\
                    textField: 'text',\
                    panelWidth: 350,\
                    multiple:true,\
                    formatter: formatItem,\
                    label: 'Language:',\
                    labelPosition: 'top'\
                    ">"+"
        </div>"
}
```

ut What chalanges I am facing is

1. Not able to create correct input tag element which causing error.

Here example :

In first case :

input tag is

```
"<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="url: "JSON/combobox_data1.json",method: "get",valueField: "id",textField: "text",                    panelWidth: 350,multiple:true,label: "Language:",labelPosition: "top">"
```

In second case input tag is :

```
"<div id="chart_line" style="width:26%; background-color: lightblue;"><input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="                    url: " json="" combobox_data1.json",="" method:="" "get",="" valuefield:="" "id",="" textfield:="" "text",="" panelwidth:="" 350,="" multiple:true,="" label:="" "language:",="" labelposition:="" "top"=""></div>"
```

Now Please help me how to fix this.

Comment: You may use jquery, has an option to append html to div id with $("#divId").html("<html></html>")

Comment: In my JS code ?

Comment: yes, but you need to import jquery library if not imported first !

Comment: Ya, What worrying me I imported my jquery library in html. Cheking how to import in javascript.

Comment: Try rewriting this question in a much simpler way.  The idea I have about what you want is a broken idea and thus I (probably others) can't help you. You need to split the problem down into small sections, what was your original idea, what you have tried and why you tried it the way you did and why is that not working together with the errors/warnings you got?

Comment: @Starx I updated my question

Comment: Much better, the first problem I can see is the function and implementation is wrong. See fixed one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q062dxns/) and see if it solve the problem.

Comment: @David please see my answer below and if it works for you.

Comment: @ZachSadler Sure let me try this

Comment: Not answering the question, but I recommend the `select2` jQuery plugin for combo boxes and select boxes. I had good experience with it. https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: Depending on which browsers you want to support you might want to use Template Literals from ES2015 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). These would make your templating js code much more concise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to add a `data-options` attribute dynamically:

```
document.getElementById('combobox1').setAttribute('data-options', '{GENERATED OPTIONS}');
```